# Vagrant omnibus with proxyconf plugin

Tags: proxy, vagrant, chef-infra

I'm having issues running the vagrant omnibus plugin behind a proxy.

It seems that the proxy configuration does not take on the first vagrant up. On first 'up', the omnibus installer times out while trying to download the chef packages. Then if I 'vagrant halt' and 'vagrant up' again, the download completes and the new version of chef gets installed.

Is there a way to force the proxy settings to refresh, or am I doing something wrong in my Vagrantfile?

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
    config.proxy.http     = "myproxy"
    config.proxy.https    = "myproxy"
  end

  config.omnibus.chef_version = "11.8.2"
  ...
```

Using the latest version of the plugins.

```
vagrant plugin list
vagrant-login (1.0.1, system)
vagrant-omnibus (1.4.1)
vagrant-proxyconf (1.3.2)
vagrant-share (1.1.0, system)
```

Cheers,
Marcus.

Comment: It is supposed to work. Could you run the initial `up` command with the `--debug` flag and gist/pastebin all the output.

Comment: Gist output here:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7c6a1019867c1eb0a756

Answer (score 0):

Looking through [the code](https://github.com/schisamo/vagrant-omnibus/blob/master/lib/vagrant-omnibus/action/install_chef.rb) I see no support for proxies. What you can do is copy the install script to a local server behind the proxy and use that instead. You could also try using vagrant-cachier.

Comment: There doesn't need to be specific proxy support in the omnibus plugin - it should just use the system proxy settings to download the packages. That's why it works on the 2nd run because the proxy has been set correctly. My issue is to get it working on the initial run which should be possible using the proxyconf plugin.